# How to setup open each external link in new tab?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How I can set up in nextjs open each external link in new tab, without adding each time to link "_blank" etc? I want that this setup working also with Link, a href, and markdown in md files?

Any ideas?

Comment: Make a custom `Link` component that has `_blank` to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the base URL and target in your `_app.js` / `_app.tsx` file. Add the [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag

```
<base target="_blank"></base>
```

inside the `<Head>` tag.

Comment: This is how it is supposed to work, I agree, but it does not in may case.

Answer (score -2):

```
<Link href={url}>
  <a target="_blank">Click this link</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: I want to set up a global change for each link.
Not added _blank for each link, any ideas?

Comment: You should make a custom Link component and use it where you want. It's another question.