# How can I use target="blank" in an external link on MDX?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown

I am creating a blog with NextJS and MDX, and I would like to add a `target="_blank"` to external links.

Normally I do it with regular Markdown using the following format `[words](link){:target="blank"}` but this is not working properly in MDX.

Comment: Additional attributes on a hyperlink (e.g. with the curly braces syntax you noted) might not be a standard markdown implementation anyways, although other flavors might (e.g. [Kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#links-and-images) support such syntax. If opening links in a new tab is an important requirement, it might be quicker and easier to write a straight HTML element for it (i.e. `<a href...>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I believe you are looking for is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71677705,

i.e. adding

```html
<base target="_blank"></base>
```

to your `<Head>` element in i.e. your _app.js or layout.js script.

This makes the rendered markdown urls to be opened in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you. I marked as accepted answer. I would like to know if at the day of today there is any way to do this but at selected elements and not the base.